# How do I impose a CONSTRAINT on a TEXT column in PostgreSQL 12?

Tags: postgresql, constraint

I want a column with a single text character as a classifier so it's not worth the overhead creating another whole table and relating to it.

How do I constrain the column to a list of acceptable characters?

E.g. how would I constrain column `my_classifier CHAR(1) NOT NULL,` to one of [abcd]?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method to do it:

```
create table test
(
  dd char NOT NULL,
  constraint dd_c check ( dd in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
);
```

Comment: You might wish to consider using the TEXT data type as covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/470530)?

Comment: @zsheep - thanks.

Comment: @Verace - thanks, but this field stores a config data element for an external tool and I want to constrain the value to only those that are acceptible. The link you provided doesn't seem to deal with this, only constraining the length. But thanks anyway

Comment: You can also add a second constraint `CHECK LENGTH(field_name) = 1`? Apparently, AIUI, all of the `CHAR/VARCHAR/TEXT` types have the same underlying `C` code. `CHECK` constraints can very much apply to the `TEXT` datatype. Just swap `TEXT` in place of `char` in @zsheep 's answer! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: @Verace Thanks so much. Yes, I saw multiple constrants is possible. And I am not surprised the same C code is used for them all. Makes sense.

Comment: @Vérace: in general I agree with not using the dreaded `char` type. But if the intent is to always store **exactly** one character I don't think there is anything wrong with using it.

Comment: Or you can use the `"char"` type, as long as you only need ASCII characters.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I suppose that using `CHAR(1)` has the advantage of being clearer than `TEXT` with an added `CHECK` constraint (as well as the one restricting the content to a, b, c, d). The message I'm getting from Erwin Brandstetter's post (referred to above) is that, all things being equal, there is no reason **not** to use `TEXT`.

Comment: there are three draw backs to CHAR,  ASCII only, the padding and MAX length,   if none of these are issues  use CHAR if those are possible issues in the future use TEXT.   The way TEXT is handled in postgresql is very different compared to other DB's comparing, indexing,and storage being three big differences.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The reason I specifically chose CHAR over TEXT is because I need to limit it to 1 character, which must be one from a fixed list, and I want to conserve memory and disk space. These requirements will never change and if they do an entirely new solution will require an entirely new table or database.